# Retrofit transform my fields Int in String

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to use retrofit library.
I have my fun :

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
fun login(@Field("field1") field1: String,
          @Field("field2") field2: String,
          @Field("field3") field3: Int = 0

): Observable<String>
```

and the definition of my retrofit object :

```
Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("")
                .client(get())
                .build()

 retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java)
            .login(UserManager.username, UserManager.password, editextToken.text.toString().toInt())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(

                    {

                        updateUiLogin()


                        val token = JwtManager.decodeTokenClaims(it)
                        UserManager.jwtToken = it

                        toast("Connexion réussis")

                    },
                    { e ->

                        e as HttpException
                        updateUiLogin()

                        toast(R.string.an_error_occured)
                        Log.w(TAG, e.message())
                    }
            )
```

but when i do my Request my "field3" Field is received as String to server.

[image]

I do to not be converted to String ?

Thank's

Comment: post the json that you are sending to the server, and also the call the statement that you are making ..!! `retrofitservice.login(x,x,x)`

Comment: `add logger interceptor` to retrofit and post the log ( the json that is sent to the server) .

Comment: I mean you are technically always sending a string to your server, sounds like your server does not know how to turn it back into an int.

Comment: OkHttp: --> POST https://domain/api/v1/login http/1.1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: 50
04-25 15:58:36.396 22171-22270/com.sanilea.itineraire D/OkHttp: username=admin&password=password&_auth_code=111111
04-25 15:58:36.397 22171-22270/ D/OkHttp: --> END POST (50-byte body)

Comment: @tyczj i tried with postoman and it work so i think it's really Retrofit the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of @FormUrlEncoded and @Field. If I save my user like this:

```
@POST("users")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<User> registerFormUser(@Field("name") String name,
                            @Field("verified_acc") boolean verified_acc,
                            @Field("points") int points);
```

then the JSON result will be:

```
{
    "name": "Robert",
    "verified_acc": "false",
    "points": "0",
    "id": 8
}
```

So my boolean and int values are now strings.

But if you save it like this:

```
@POST("users")
Call<User> registerUser(@Body User user);
```

then the JSON result will be:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "George",
    "points": 0,
    "verified_acc": false
}
```

The only problem with the second aproach is that it changes the order alphabetically. If you have no problem with that, it's ok to save it without convert the fields to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I created an object like this:

```
data class UserLogin(val username: String, val password: String, val code: Int = 0)
```

And make it

```
@POST("login")
fun login(@Body user: UserLogin

): Observable<String>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put instead of int - long.

Example:

```
@Field("_auth_code") authCode: long = 0
```